# How to properly use item_loader in Scrapy? Item_loader class not working properly

Tags: scrapy

I pass scrapy items via the meta property to a callback function like so:

```
def parse_VendorDetails(self, response):
    loader = XPathItemLoader(response.meta['item'], response=response)

    print loader.get_collected_values('testField') <-- returns empty value
    print response.meta['item']['testField'] <-- return expected value
```

the first print outputs an empty list. the second print returns the value as expected.
What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a [bug in *ItemLoaders*](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/208#issuecomment-11469555),`get_output_value()` and `get_collected_values()` ignore `item` parameters and only look at `ItemLoader._values` so there is some inconsistent behavior in these methods in that loaded data via `load_item()` is not returned:

```
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
>>> il = ItemLoader(response=response, item=dict(foo=1))
>>> il.add_value('bar', 3)
>>> il._values
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'bar': [3]})

>>> il.item
{'foo': 1}

>>> il.get_output_value('foo')
[]

>>> il.get_output_value('bar')
[3]

>>> il.get_collected_values('foo')
[]

>>> il.get_collected_values('bar')
[3]
```

You can install [the proposed patch](https://github.com/stav/scrapy/commit/415048237ce4ec2712bf4bc5653424ca070a3f7c) or just not use `get_collected_values`. If you install the patch you can use the `values` parameter with this patch we experience a more sane result:

```
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
>>> il = ItemLoader(response=response, item={}, values=dict(foo=1))
>>> il.add_value('bar', 3)
>>> il._values
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'foo': [1], 'bar': [3]})

>>> il.item
{}

>>> il.get_output_value('foo')
[1]

>>> il.get_output_value('bar')
[3]

>>> il.get_collected_values('foo')
[1]

>>> il.get_collected_values('bar')
[3]
```